details summary transition inconsistent
I have built a "sliding menu" using details and summary tag. It is meant to smoothly slide and fade in and out as you toggle details. Below is the template with Tailwind utility classes (Note that this is in Angular but the problem might not be necessarily related to the Angular side of the implementation and could be purely a CSS issue)
<details
  class="relative cursor-pointer whitespace-nowrap overflow-hidden"
  #detailsElement
  [attr.style]="style"
  (toggle)="cdr.detectChanges()">
  <summary
    class="inline-block align-top relative top-0 left-0 opacity-100 w-full p-f-xs-tight fade-slide bg-yellow-400"
    aria-haspopup="menu"
    [attr.aria-expanded]="detailsElement.open"
    [style.left]="detailsElement.open ? '-100%' : '0'"
    [style.opacity]="detailsElement.open ? '0' : '1'">
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center w-full">
      <span class="text-pretty text-step-1">
        {{ label() }}
      </span>
      <span class="iconify material-symbols-light--arrow-forward size-f-s-tight"></span>
    </div>
  </summary>
  <div
    class="inline-block relative align-top w-full opacity-0 fade-slide bg-green-400"
    [style.left]="detailsElement.open ? '-100%' : '0'"
    [style.opacity]="detailsElement.open ? '1' : '0'">
    <div>
      <button class="icon-button" (click)="fold(detailsElement)">
        <span class="iconify material-symbols-light--arrow-back"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-f-s">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</details>


where .fade-slide is:
.fade-slide {
  transition:
    opacity 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1),
    left 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1);
}

and fold is:
  fold(element: HTMLDetailsElement) {
    element.open = false;
  }

Apparently the left transition and opacity transition are inconsistent. Sometimes it does fade-slide in and out, sometimes it only slides in when opened but without opacity transition.somethimes it doesnt transition the left and opacity all together. and other combination.
